# Getting count from large tables

Tags: oracle, count

I was trying to get the count from a table with millions of entries. My query looks somewhat like this:

```
Select count(*)
from Users
where status = 'A' and office_id = '000111' and user_type = 'C'
```

Status can be A or C, User Type can be C or R.
Status, Office_id and User_type are Strings

The result has around 10 million rows, and its taking a lot of time. I just want the total count.

Would appreciate if anyone could tell me why its taking this much time, and workaround if any.

Do let me know in case of any more details required.

The database engine is Oracle 11g

Edit: I Added index for all three columnns. Still theres no improvement. Also tried the below query, but it always returns the total count in the table without checking the conditions.

```
SELECT COUNT(office_id_key) 
FROM Users
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Users WHERE status = 'A' AND office_id = '000111' AND user_type = 'C')
```

Comment: Is your age field a text field? Just wondering

Comment: Run an explain plan on your query (and post the output too?).  What datatype is the `age` column? What indexing exists on the `Employee` table?

Comment: Can you provide table defintion in MySQL?

Comment: yes its a text field. Sorry I just pasted a sample query. I will update it now

Comment: @Chillax Obvious question is why is a number stored as a text field?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. All are text fields

Comment: Are you sure their types are TEXT? Are they CHAR

Comment: @Chillax, I've seen where some ID's will be numeric for most cases, but special cases may add a character code. 00011 for employees, A0011 for admin or something like that.

Comment: Yup they are VARCHAR. Yes, that is the exact reason why the ID is a VARCHAR.

Comment: @Chillax Let's start from the obvious.  Do all your users have status = 'A', office_id = '000111', and user_type = 'C'?  Can you post the output of `SELECT DISTINCT status FROM Users` and same for office_id, and user_type?

Comment: @Karlson Not at office now.So wouldnt be able to run the queries. As mentioned in my question, status can only be "C" or "A" . User type can be "C" or "E". Office_id can be anything with length 6.

Comment: @Chillax That's find but what is it actually?  If all rows match the criteria you put in you will get full table row count and no index will help you.

Comment: @Karlson There are around 36 million records. I guess there are around 2 million records which satisfy the condition. I need to get this count which is taking forever.

Comment: @Chillax How many columns in the table?  As @MarcusAdams suggested can you post the results of `EXPLAIN` on that select?  Where does Oracle 11g comes into play?

Comment: @Karlson Wont be able to get the exact details until tom. There are around 25-30 columns. Database is Oracle 11g

Comment: @Chillax Are you trying to pull from MySQL via Oracle?

Comment: @Karlson Its just Oracle. No MySQl. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just simply create indexes on the table on `age` and `place` this way your search will be faster then simply scanning the entire table for these values.

```
CREATE INDEX age_index ON Employee(age);
CREATE INDEX place_index ON Employee(place);
```

This should speed up the process.

**AMENDED BASED ON QUERY CHANGE**

```
CREATE INDEX status_index ON Users(status);
CREATE INDEX office_id_index ON Users(office_id);
CREATE INDEX user_type_index ON Users(user_type);
```

Comment: Author changed the names of the tables/fields, but this advice is solid. Add some indexes to the appropriate columns.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i wouldn't be able to try it until tomorrow. Will update tomorrow.

Comment: @gfortune Amended the answer. :)

Comment: @Karlson One doubt, wouldn't adding indexes slow the updation of the table?

Comment: @Karlson Have updated my question. Could you please look into it?

Comment: MySQL will use just one of those indexes, whichever it thinks will return the least rows, which is office_id_index.

Comment: @Chillax It's a trade-off if you have an index it will obviously impact inserts and some updates, but will make searching faster.  The only time it will have a significant enough impact so not to have them is when you are doing bulk inserts.

Comment: @Karlson I have added the index, but the search is still very slow. Can it be done with some change in the query?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to create the following multi-column index on the `Users` table to improve the query:

```
(office_id, status, user_type)
```

The database can use a "covering" index with `COUNT(*)`. Create the index with the columns in that order, due to cardinality.

Comment: Thanks. Is it something like this :CREATE INDEX count_index ON Users(office_id, status, user_type);   ?

Comment: @Chillax, yes, that's fine, though technically, I would put a space between `Users` and `(`.

Comment: Adding index didn't improve things. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Let's see full query. Are you showing the whole thing? Also, please show the Explain results.

Comment: Yup thats the full query. The result is 36355199 which is the total count from the table(without the conditions).

Comment: With the "covering" index above, please run the query with `EXPLAIN` in front of it like `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and include the full results in your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the indexes, I think changing where to where exists and a subquery may help as well.

Edit2: removed exists as it was returning all valid, usually the subquery has multiple joins, but I guess the case with one table returns all true. I read that count is optimized to act similar to exists when it has only one table and no where clause, so I treat the results as a table. Hopefully, this will have the same quick results.

```
select count(1) from
(select 1 from Employee where age = '25' and place = 'bricksgate')
```

Edit: When you use 'where exists' the db server doesn't load your data into memory and also takes advantage of the indexes because you will be reading values from the indexes not doing costly table lookups. You may also want to change count(*) to count(place) - that way it will limit the fields to an indexed field as well.

In your original query, your data was doing table lookups and then loading them into memory just to be counted.

Comment: Thanks. Will do it tomorrow and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: just tried the above query. It returned the total count in the table. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I edited the query to use the optimized form of count, hopefully that will help. :)

Answer (score -1):

count(1) works faster than count(*)

Comment: You might want to be a little more specific, but you will get much bigger bang if you don't have to scan the entire table.

Comment: There is no logical difference between COUNT(1) and COUNT(*), and no performance difference.

Comment: On versions 7.x and lower (Oracle), count(1) had better performance than count(*).